# Is there a newspaper or online magazine with a REST API for article comments?

Tags: data-request, media

I wonder whether there is a newspaper website or an online magazine that has a REST API for querying articles, but also for *fetching comments from the readers*. Not comments on scholarly information, but comments on current events.

For which media outlet can this be done without web scraping, just with a few API requests?

This could be useful for text mining (sentiment analysis, and categorization, user analysis).

I'm only familiar with the Guardian API and the API of "Die Zeit" (a German weekly)

Can I use one of Facebook's APIs for this (I think some newspapers recently decided to become, somehow, embedded inside Facebook)?